# How to change Terminal Emulator font size (Ubuntu, XFCE4 remote session with X2Go)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, remote-desktop, desktop, xfce

I've google and read the "How to change Terminal Emulator..." Q/As but all talk to Edit/Preferences menu.

Remotely accessing a Ubuntu desktop's Terminal Emulator via X2Go client using XFCE4 I do not have such a menu...

(Ubuntu 16.04, Xfce Desktop 4.12, X2Go client for Windows 4.1.2.0)

What am I missing?

[image: []

Answer (score 1):

Terminal Emulator is a fairly broad term. There are numerous terminal emulators available.

The one pictured looks like XTerm so:

Press and hold Control and then press and hold right mouse button for the VT Font menu.

[image]